Is YAMNet model can be used with the hub.KerasLayer?
I am attempting to use YAMNet for transfer learning to perform speech command recognition. I plan to train the model using the mini speech commands dataset from the simple audio project. The goal is to deploy the trained model on an Android device.
I have written the following code to create a new model using the YAMNet architecture with a custom classifier for speech command recognition:
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

num_classes = 8
waveform = np.zeros(3 * 16000, dtype=np.float32)
new_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/google/yamnet/1", output_key='embeddings', output_shape=[None, 1024], trainable=False),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')
])
new_model.build(waveform)

new_model.summary()

However, I'm encountering an error when trying to run this setup:
    "name": "TypeError",
    "message": "Dimension value must be integer or None or have an __index__ method, got value '0.0' with type '<class 'numpy.float32'>'",

I suspect the error might be related to how the input is being processed or maybe an issue with the configuration of the KerasLayer for YAMNet. Can anyone help identify what might be causing this error and suggest how to resolve it?
04-25-2024 Updated my code and an error occurred.

Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

the issue you have reported is input_dimension issue.
new_model.build(waveform.reshape(1, 3, 16000))


Thank you for your response. I tried the code you provided, but encountered the following error: "name": "TypeError", "message": "only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index". Could you please tell me the issue number reported? Most of the information online uses hub.load for transfer learning with YAMNet. I'm not sure if YAMNet can be used as a hub.KerasLayer to be added as a layer to a custom model.
